# how to use date and time pickers in react native

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I created a react native form and I want to add date and time Picker values to the form and the save them to backend. I have tried few libraries but failed.

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker)**

```
# using npm
$ npm i react-native-modal-datetime-picker @react-native-community/datetimepicker

# using yarn
$ yarn add react-native-modal-datetime-picker @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```

**Example**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

const Example = () => {
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = date => {
    console.warn("A date has been picked: ", date);
    hideDatePicker();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Show Date Picker" onPress={showDatePicker} />
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

**SIMPLE EXAMPLE FOR YOUR PROBLEM**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import DateTimePicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

export default class ExampleClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isDatePickerVisible: false,
      pickedDate: ""
    };
  }

  //Date Picker handling methods
  hideDatePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isDatePickerVisible: false });
  };

  handleDatePicked = date => {
    const mdate = date.toString().split(" ");
    this.setState({
      pickedDate: mdate[1] + " " + mdate[2] + ", " + mdate[3]
    });
    this.hideDatePicker();
  };

  showDatePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isDatePickerVisible: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* Your View Here */}
        <DateTimePicker
          mode="date"
          isVisible={this.state.isDatePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
          onCancel={this.hideDatePicker}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: Gald to help! If you found this useful don't forget to make upvote and mark as the correct answer for your question @Bhargavireddy

Comment: Did you follow all the steps? Recheck it and install all the dependencies as you see in the documentation

Comment: @Bhargavireddy you need to intsall two packages before copy above code

Comment: I've added import {DateTimePicker} from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';

Comment: Am trying to add this for android

Comment: @Bhargavireddy It should work. Read package official documentation

Comment: error: constructor RCTDateTimePickerPackage in class RCTDateTimePickerPackage cannot be applied to given types;
      new RCTDateTimePickerPackage(),
      ^
  required: Activity
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: Which os are you testing Android or iOS? Remove node_modules folder and reinstall using npm install and run. NOTE: Do Not Link Packages Manually

Comment: Am running on Android.. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the node modules still am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of work but, I can summarize it. Even once you get datetime working. You still have to convert a react native timestamp into a date and time. And then you have to convert 24 hour time into 12 hour time and then the date is backwards like dd/mm/yyyy so you have to probably switch that as well to mm/dd/yyyy finally. But here's the whole solution! Please comment for any fixes. Should be perfect I think.

Imports:

```
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
```

State:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
const [chosenDate, setChosenDate] = useState("Empty");
```

onChange Method:

```
  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');

// This maintains the current date after Selection!
setDate(currentDate);

let tempDate = new Date(currentDate);
let fDate = tempDate.getDate() + '/' + (tempDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + tempDate.getFullYear();

let hour = tempDate.getHours()
let minutes = tempDate.getMinutes()
let meridian = "AM"  // AM or PM


if (hour >= 12) {
  hour = hour - 12;
  meridian = "PM";
}
if (hour == 0) {
  hour = 12;
}

const splited = fDate.split('/');
const dateProper = [splited[1]+"/" + splited[0] +"/" + splited[2]];

setChosenDate(dateProper[0] + hour + ":" + minutes + " " + meridian)
console.log(dateProper[0] + '\n' + hour + ":" + minutes + " " + meridian)
}
```

JSX:

```
<Text style={{
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingTop:8
  }}>Start Date and Time</Text>

  <DateTimePicker
    testID="dateTimePicker"
    value={date || new Date()}
    mode="datetime"
    display="default"
    is24Hour={true}
    onChange={onChange}
    textColor="#fff"
    style={{ padding:10 }}
  />
```